# LoadFrom and context

Tags: .net, reflection, assemblies, appdomain, assembly-loading

I am loading through `Assembly.LoadFrom` an assembly (A) which is stored outside of the application base path; the assembly I load references another .net assembly (B) in the same directory.

When I try to use some methods of the A assembly, Fusion logs reveal that the system is trying to load B.dll from the application base directory rather than the parent directory of A.dll.

I added a listener to `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve`, which is invoked with the sender `AppDomain` having a message saying "There are no context policies.", and the `ResolveEventArgs.RequestingAssembly` property set to `null`.

Shouldn't `LoadFrom` allow searching for an assembly's dependencies in its parent directory?

Comment: Nope, it does not work like that (unfortunately). I have a similar problem where by intercepting the default/native loader would be beneficial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, I think it should but leppie is correct, it doesn't. Here is a detailed MSDN article about the [assembly probing sequence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15hyw9x3.aspx). There have been several times where I had the exact same issue and using the AssemblyResolve event is the only way.

Answer (score 0):

Well, actually it should! And it does. See:

- [https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/suzcook/2003/05/29/choosing-a-binding-context/)
- [https://learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.loadfrom?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Reflection_Assembly_LoadFrom_System_String_)

An while CLR still tries to resolve dependencies of assembly (A) using GAC and appbase directory, it will also look in the folder (A) was loaded from.